# Uploads will not pass 'INITIALIZED' state

Tags: javascript, android, automated-tests, aws-device-farm

I'm setting up automated tests with AWS Device Farm, and for some reason my upload using the API is just sitting with the Initialized status. It's sending the createUpload() and getting a response with the URL, then sending a request to the URL with the file I want to upload. I'm polling getUpload() every 30 seconds for a change in the status. Here is the main part of my code and the console logs:

https://gist.github.com/asanders-tester/682534925ac314d0805a6dfec547e57f

https://gist.github.com/asanders-tester/40c3e11acd5491aaff7256144f80d8b0

Could anybody provide some insight into what I'm doing wrong? Similar posts here are saying the URL is likely incorrect, but I can't find anything wrong with it.

Cross-posted on AWS Developer Forums: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=346232&tstart=0

Comment: I noticed in the URL the access key is one that can't be found anywhere in the environment files; it definitely doesn't match the one being sent with the credentials. Has anybody run into this issue and been able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The upload lifecycle for an upload in AWS Device Farm is that:

1. It will start in status INITIALIZED
2. Once your data has been PUT to the presigned URL, it will nearly-immediately enter the status PROCESSING
3. Shortly-after, the upload will enter a status of SUCCESS or FAILED

It appears that your https request with options is failing to send the data as expected. Can you look into adding an option like "port: 443," to it, as well as printing additional response details when the request is complete?